# Graph API - Sharepoint document library permissions not returned

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I discovered today that permissions are not returned anymore using this query using a regular user (it is working with a Global admin account):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<siteId>/lists/<listId>/drive/items/<folderId>?&expand=Permissions
```

The list of permission returned is empty.

[image]

Same result using

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<siteId>/lists/<listId>/drive/items/<folderId>/Permissions
```

Based on [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-permissions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#access-to-sharing-permissions), *For a non-owner caller, only the sharing permissions that apply to the caller are returned.*

If I'm going directly in SharePoint with the user, I see the right permissions.

Answer (score 0):

According the [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-permissions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#remarks)

The permissions relationship of `DriveItem` cannot be expanded as part of a call to get `DriveItem` or a collection of `DriveItems`. You must access the permissions property directly.

Could you try to call this endpoint?

```
GET /v1.0/sites/<siteId>/lists/<listId>/drive/items/<folderId>/permissions
```

Resources:

[Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-permissions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: Same result. An empty list with a regular user.
The expand stuff worked for many months. Don't know why this is not working anymore.